# iOS VideoPreview Landscape is upside down

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, avcam

For some reason when I orient the phone to landscape mode the camera preview is upside down (flipped horizontally). I'm using the sample project that Xamarin ported; [AVCamBarcode](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios10/AVCamBarcode/).

I ended up coming up with a half complete fix by using GeometryFlipped in landscape orientation. However, now the drawn barcodes are not drawn in the correct locations in landscape mode.

1. Is this a device/os issue or is the sample incomplete?
2. What is the recommended method to correct this?

   ```
   public override void ViewWillTransitionToSize (CGSize toSize, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator coordinator)
   {
       base.ViewWillTransitionToSize (toSize, coordinator);

       var videoPreviewLayerConnection = PreviewView.VideoPreviewLayer.Connection;
       if (videoPreviewLayerConnection != null) {
           var deviceOrientation = UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Orientation;
           if (!deviceOrientation.IsPortrait () && !deviceOrientation.IsLandscape ())
               return;

           var newVideoOrientation = VideoOrientationFor (deviceOrientation);
           var oldSize = View.Frame.Size;
           var oldVideoOrientation = videoPreviewLayerConnection.VideoOrientation;
           videoPreviewLayerConnection.VideoOrientation = newVideoOrientation;

           //THIS IS THE HALF FIX I CAME UP WITH
           if (deviceOrientation.IsLandscape())
               videoPreviewLayerConnection.VideoPreviewLayer.GeometryFlipped = true;
           else
               videoPreviewLayerConnection.VideoPreviewLayer.GeometryFlipped = false;
           //END FIX

           // When we transition to the new size, we need to adjust the region
           // of interest's origin and size so that it stays anchored relative
           // to the camera.
           coordinator.AnimateAlongsideTransition (context => {
               var oldRegion = PreviewView.RegionOfInterest;
               var newRegion = new CGRect ();

               if (oldVideoOrientation == LandscapeRight && newVideoOrientation == LandscapeLeft) {
                   newRegion = oldRegion.WithX (oldSize.Width - oldRegion.X - oldRegion.Width);
               } else if (oldVideoOrientation == LandscapeRight && newVideoOrientation == Portrait) {
                   newRegion.X = toSize.Width - oldRegion.Y - oldRegion.Height;
                   newRegion.Y = oldRegion.X;
                   newRegion.Width = oldRegion.Height;
                   newRegion.Height = oldRegion.Width;
               } else if (oldVideoOrientation == LandscapeLeft && newVideoOrientation == LandscapeRight) {
                   newRegion = oldRegion.WithX (oldSize.Width - oldRegion.X - oldRegion.Width);
               } else if (oldVideoOrientation == LandscapeLeft && newVideoOrientation == Portrait) {
                   newRegion.X = oldRegion.Y;
                   newRegion.Y = oldSize.Width - oldRegion.X - oldRegion.Width;
                   newRegion.Width = oldRegion.Height;
                   newRegion.Height = oldRegion.Width;
               } else if (oldVideoOrientation == Portrait && newVideoOrientation == LandscapeRight) {
                   newRegion.X = oldRegion.Y;
                   newRegion.Y = toSize.Height - oldRegion.X - oldRegion.Width;
                   newRegion.Width = oldRegion.Height;
                   newRegion.Height = oldRegion.Width;
               } else if (oldVideoOrientation == Portrait && newVideoOrientation == LandscapeLeft) {
                   newRegion.X = oldSize.Height - oldRegion.Y - oldRegion.Height;
                   newRegion.Y = oldRegion.X;
                   newRegion.Width = oldRegion.Height;
                   newRegion.Height = oldRegion.Width;
               }

               PreviewView.SetRegionOfInterestWithProposedRegionOfInterest (newRegion);
           }, context => {
               sessionQueue.DispatchAsync (() => {
                   metadataOutput.RectOfInterest = PreviewView.VideoPreviewLayer.MapToLayerCoordinates (PreviewView.RegionOfInterest);
               });
               // Remove the old metadata object overlays.
               RemoveMetadataObjectOverlayLayers ();
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Edit

```
AVCaptureVideoOrientation VideoOrientationFor (UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation)
{
    switch (deviceOrientation) {
    case UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait:
        return Portrait;
    case UIDeviceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown:
        return PortraitUpsideDown;
    case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
        return LandscapeLeft;
    case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
        return LandscapeRight;
    default:
        throw new InvalidProgramException ();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's in `VideoOrientationFor()`

Comment: @LouFranco Added it to my post.

Comment: I know this is crazy, but the equivalent in my app has landscape left and right reversed (returning left for right and vice versa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device and video orientation have different meanings for landscape.

[The docs say (for video)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideoorientation):

> case landscapeLeft
>
> Indicates that video should be oriented horizontally, top on the right.
>
> case landscapeRight
>
> Indicates that video should be oriented horizontally, top on the left.

but [device orientation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation) says:

> case landscapeLeft
>
> The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the right side.
>
> case landscapeRight
>
> The device is in landscape mode, with the device held upright and the home button on the left side.

So, you need to change to this:

```
case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
    return LandscapeRight;
case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
    return LandscapeLeft;
```

Comment: I thought about trying that but it felt so obviously wrong. Thanks a bunch @Lou Franco